# Keeping the .enrich index updated to source index elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using the new [enrich API of Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/put-enrich-policy-api.html) (ver 7.11),
to my understanding, I need to execute the policy "PUT /_enrich/policy/my-policy/_execute" each time when the source index changed, which lead to the creation of a new .enrich index.
is there an option to make it happen automatically and avoid of index creation on every change of the source index?

Answer (score 1):

This is not (yet) supported and there have been [other reports](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/58925) of similar needs.

It seems to be complex to provide the ability to regularly update an enrich index based on a changing source index and the issue above explains why.

That feature might be available some day, [something seems to be in the works](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/73407). I agree it would be super useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a default pipeline to your index.  that pipeline will process the documents.

See [here](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/how-do-we-use-an-ingest-node-in-elasticsearch-to-enrich-logs-and-metrics_597453).